# filtering matching values from list of object using underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I am using `UnderscoreJs` in my project. I have to filter an array containing object having properties. I need to filter based on the values. The value can be of any property of the object. ex: "mini" should fetch both "toyota" and "Honda" since "mini" is present as part of both the objects

```
[{ name:"Toyota minivan", id:"506", size: "large" }, { name:"Honda Civic", id:"619", size: "mini" }]
```

How to do using Underscore. I have tried the following approach but not working.

```
var searchStr="mini";
var evens = _.filter([arrayData], function(obj){ return _.contains(obj, searchStr); });
```

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_.contains` only works on arrays, so you need to grab the values from each object first and then check if any of them contain the search string. I've used [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in this example, together with `indexOf` to match the string.

```
var searchStr="mini";
var mini = _.filter(arr, function (obj) {
    return _.values(obj).some(function (el) {
        return el.indexOf(searchStr) > -1;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kyw8nc7s/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have done this with simple if condition so that in future if you want to list mini in one array and large in one array so you can do easily. I have checked the object property if matched then assigned to new list. here is my code. and check out demo here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syqygbdc/)

```
 var list=[{ name:"Toyota minivan", id:"506", size: "large" }, 
              { name:"Honda Civic", id:"619", size: "mini" },
              {name:"zen",id:"606",size:"mini"}]; 
   var result=_.filter(list, function(obj){
                  if(obj.size=='mini'){ 
                    var matchedcars=obj; 
                    console.log("result"+JSON.stringify(matchedcars));
                  } 
                   return matchedcars;
   });
     alert("result"+JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: This solution works partially since the `obj.size=='mini'` is hardcoded. The check should be done by verifying all the properties of the object and not specific to `size` property.

Comment: what you mean by partially? and what you accepted is works for index purpose only if in future you add new properties then?? index changes,  i have used such type of comparison in my project and it works fine. anyhow bro you got answer thats imp. bye